# Uninitialized constant BCrpyt when silencing in test.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I am having an error when running spork.
../config/environments/test.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in ': uninitialized constant BCrpyt (NameError)

This is in my test.rb:

require 'bcrypt'
  silence_warnings do
    BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrpyt::Engine::MIN_COST
  end

I required bcrypt, so i do not know why BCrypt is uninitialized.

I am using the bcrypt gem -v 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo.

You typed:

```
require 'bcrypt' silence_warnings do BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrpyt::Engine::MIN_COST end
```

should be:

```
require 'bcrypt' silence_warnings do BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST end
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not see the difference between the two lines. Maybe I should just copy and paste yours.

Comment: BCrpyt != BCrypt  (you spelled the MIN_COST Bcrypt incorrectly)

Answer (score 1):

Install bcrypt-ruby gem using following command

```
    'gem install bcrypt-ruby'
```

Include this gem in your gemfile

```
    gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
```

This should solve your issue, If not, try to run 'bundle install'.